# NTC for inrush for DC/DC with DC input voltage

Tags: power, dc-dc-converter, current-limiting, thermistor

I want to limit the current to my DC/DC input. At first, I wanted to use a resistor, however, I also came across an NTC for inrush limiting. So I basically want to change R1 with an NTC.

The specs for the circuit is the input current for the DC/DC is around 1.4A during normal conditions. How do I go about selecting an NTC for this application?

U3 requires around 4.17A (supply power to the relay and other stuff as well) to turn on and therefore turn the relay on. The efficiency of the DC/DC is around 80%, hence the 1.4A at the DC/DC input

Most NTC online has to do with AC power and not DC power. So I am not sure of what equestions to use.

[image]

Comment: That things are called PTC fuse. Why NTC?

Comment: @user263983 this is for an inrush current limiter. I need the resistance to decrease as the temperature increases.... NTC also are generally used in this type of applications as comp;ared to PTC fuses because of their inverse relationship between temp and resistance...

Comment: What temperature? Ambient,  IC's? Modify your guestion.

Comment: NTC implies a Negative Temperature Coefficient - the resistance goes *down* as the device warms up.  So if you wanted to use them in this application, they will have to start off at a higher resistance.  For 100uF, R1=10Ω would limit instantaneous current at t=0 to 4.8A and tau=100µF*10Ω = 1ms.  If R1=100Ω, t0 = 0.48A and 2/3rds charged in 10ms.

Comment: @user263983 so when the button SW1 is pressed the resistance of the NTC will be the highest, as steady-state occurs, the temperature of the NTC/ICL will increase, therefore decreasing the resistance and allowing the max current to flow.

Comment: Hi JoeyB, So, you still not buying the scheme of switching the power directly, without R1, h h ... And, I still think your best option will be using a heavy duty SW without R1. You may add a cap, shunt to SW1, though I don't expect much help. Otherwise, 1) Use a TR/FET, along with some circuitry. 2) Drive the relay coil, OR-ing (diode) with the CPU drive signal. 3)Use DPDT, and cut out heavy load while latching the relay. One more, as much the switch sees the inrush current, the relay contact sees heavy current at contact open. That causes ARC.

Comment: @jay the relay contact "load" is not inductive so I do not see heavy voltage that will cause any issue of arcing when the contacts open. As stated in the previous post, the driven force behind my decision cost as well as comparing it to your other options.

Comment: @JoeyB, Oh dud, I did not know you were way to production. I thought you wanted something different, for fun, experimental. If you intend more than personal, you are definitely on a wrong track. Search how arc occurs on a contact. Arc is a path to current. It is different from high voltage discharge. I will leave you alone.